# How do I broadcast in adhoc networks?

Tags: java, ms-access

How do I broadcast a message from a single source to all nodes, and from multiple sources to all nodes?

Are there any libraries in java that may help?

Comment: I think this question needs a heck of a lot more description for anyone to be able to answer it...

Comment: The tags don't make any sense.

Comment: Can somebody please remove ms-access tag from this??

Answer (score 3):

You could look into a distributed messaging framework such as JMS.  One Open Source implementation of the protocol is Active MQ: http://activemq.apache.org/

Comment: Sounds like a Topic Messaging model to me.